# Establishing relationships between two models

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating an app of soccer stats and faced some misunderstanding about establishing relationships between models. I created two models. First of them League with the following fields

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    country = models.CharField()
    country_code = models.CharField()
```

and second Country model with following fields.

```
class Country(models.Midel):
    country = models.CharField()
    country_code = models.CharField()
```

I need to establish relationship between both models. Based on logic of my database one league row can contain only one country. Country table in database didnt contain any information about leagues related to it. In league table each row contain information about country to which league is related. I think that i should use  one-to-many relationship. Is my thoughts right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

League should have the code field, but not country.Also, the field will be a Foreign Key

Here is some pseudo code. You will need to double check syntax, on_delete stuff, max length on char fields, etc.

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    country_code = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class Country(models.Model):
    country_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True)
    country = models.CharField()
```

Comment: Why i should establish relationship based on country_code field. I want to understand your logic

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер Because that is relational db best practice. You assign each row in your table a unique value (Primary Key) and you avoid duplicating data. You don't need to store `country` in both tables, because that is duplicating data. You instead store it in `Country` and when you want to retrieve it, you join to it by using `country_code` which is a unique value in the table.

Comment: Thank you man. Now i understood. Also answer to my question is it one to many relationship ? Or one to one ?

Comment: @НаглыйСпамер one to many. One to One is a very rare relationship.

Comment: Man i want one clarifying question. I fully didnt understand why i should establish relationship using country_code field can i choose instead country_code field a country field ?